# using PhDThesisPSnPDF class

Tags: class-options

May be this is a common qusetion but I haven't found this answer. 
I'm trying to use PhDThesisPSnPDF class but writing in Italian. My only issue is to change the "Chapter" in the italian lenguages (Capitolo). 
I have no problems with bib, list of contents etc...
can some one help me?

Comment: Welcome, please give us a link where we can find the file/class/template.

Comment: ok thank you very mutch. the link is the template i'm trying to use: https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template

Comment: in the classes folder there is the class in questions

Comment: This is one of the classes that defines all language strings hardcoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `babel` fixes the issue. In the example I used a mock `thebibliography` environment just by way of example, use your own method. I also added the `oneside` option only in order to reduce the number of pages.

You have to change the text for the title page, of course.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  %times, % DON'T USE THIS OPTION
  numbered,
  print,
  index,
  oneside, % just for shortening the example
]{PhDThesisPSnPDF}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\author{Io}
\title{Titolo}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
  \maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Prova}

Testo

\begin{figure}[htp]
A
\caption{Una figura}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp]
B
\caption{Una tabella}
\end{table}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{x} Riferimento

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \maketitle` within the `titlepage` environment?

Comment: @Johannes_B Why not? That's how the class does the title page

Comment: Woul you recommend to do that or not?

Comment: I steel a little problem...how ti change for example acknowledgements in the equivalent italian word ringraziamenti? :)

Comment: @PierpaoloCroce The word “Acknowledgments” is hard coded, as well as several other instances of English words. The simplest method is to make a copy of it and fix the English into Italian.

Comment: Can explain me how to do this ? or a refence to start?

Comment: @PierpaoloCroce Copy the file, rename it, search for *Acknowledgements* change the relevant word to italian and save. Make sure your main document calls the changed name in for `\documentclass`.

Comment: the .cls file??

Comment: @PierpaoloCroce Yes.